# user enter 2 number and show prime number within the numbers,,

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I had to develop a program using c that takes as input 2 different number from user and output prime number with in the input(eg input 2 and 100 , output as prime number from2 to 100). The program should terminate non prime number and do not print.
Anyone please tell me the error in the code

```
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);

    int flag=0,num,num1,i,a;




        printf("Enter 2 number");
        scanf("%d%d",&num,&num1);


        for(i=num;i<=num1;i++){



            for(a=2;a<i;a++){

            if(i%a==0){
                flag=1;
                break;


            }
            if(flag==0){
                printf("\n%d",num);
            }

            }
        }
```

I had to develop a program using c that takes as input 2 different number from user and output prime number with in the input(eg input 2 and 100 , output was prime number from 2 to 100). The program should terminate non prime number and do not print.

Comment: Count the `{` you have 5, count the `}` you have 4. Some of the `{` and `}` that you do have are in the wrong place. Your code should not be such a mess, it makes it hard to find these kind of errors. Always indent your code correctly, remove all the blank lines.

Comment: Have a look at : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes. To figure out if something is prime. Also don't use prinft/scanf in C++, use std::cin and std::cout

Comment: Another error is the you do not print the prime number you found, you print `num` which is one of the numbers entered.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Copying identical text twice in your question does not add any value. Instead you could provide a description what your problem is. What input do you provide, what output do you get and what do you expect. Or do you get compiler errors? Which? Add an exact problem description

Comment: Two (unrelated) things: The first is that you almost never need `setbuf(stdout,NULL)`. That call seems to be plain [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). If you need to explicitly flush the `stdout` buffers do it with `fflush(stdout)`; The second thing is that you should get used to printing *trailing* newlines with `printf`. By default and when connected to a terminal, output to `stdout` is *line* buffered, which means output is written on newline. With a leading newline you output the *previous* line, not the current.

Answer (score 0):

At least this issue:

`int flag=0` should be inside the `for(i=num;i<=num1;i++){` loop to reset the prime detection for each new `i`.

---

Note: `for(a=2; a<=i/a; a++) {` much faster than `for(a=2;a<i;a++){`